# Какова синтаксическая роль оборотов с «что» и какая пунктуация при них?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор, члены-предложения

> Ты что, совсем с ума сошёл?

«Ты что» — это что? Какой это член предложения и верно ли стоит запятая?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Ты что**, совсем с ума сошёл?*

**Запятая ставится** согласно правилу Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=129#pp129

Вопросительно-восклицательные слова

1. Слова что, а что, что же, обозначающие вопросы, и слова как, как же, что же, выражающие удивление, подтверждение, согласие и т. п., за которыми следует предложение, **раскрывающее их конкретный смысл** (после них делается пауза), отделяются запятой.

Такие конструкции имеют **фразеологический характер**, каждый конкретный случай рассматривается отдельно.

В заданном примере местоимение ЧТО занимает **позицию сказуемого**, содержание которого раскрывается во второй части после запятой.

Сравнить: *Что с тобой* (= ты что)? *Совсем с ума сошёл?*